# Postgresql function returning record - accessing individual columns

Tags: function, postgresql, record

I have a function f_product_price(lab uuid, price_list uuid, product_class uuid), that returns record of useful items. 
If I use the function in FROM clause, it works fine in version 9.3:

```
select a.item_name, pl.base_price, ....
from lab l, items a,  f_product_pric(l.id, l.price_list, a.product_class) as pl
where lab.guid=? .....
```

but it I need it in version 9.2, where it returns error:

**There is an entry for table "pl", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.**

Does anybody know ***how to modify the select***?
For my purposes is sufficient to ***access individual item by name*** in select list like this :

```
select a.item_name, f_product_pric(l.id, l.price_list, a.product_class).base_price, ....
from lab l, items a .......
where lab.guid=? .....
```

But it returns syntax error at or near "."
What is the correct syntax?

Comment: the second one is correct, but why you have ".base_price" after brackets? The reason the first one is working on 9.3 is the introduction of lateral queries.

Comment: So this one should work: select a.item_name, f_product_pric(l.id, l.price_list, a.product_class), ....
from lab l, items a .......
where lab.guid=? .....

Comment: f_product_price(l.id, l.price_list, a.product_class) returns record, I can see the value '{items separated by commas}', but I need to access specific item by name. Is there any function what can do it? I expected the dot notation would be correct, but it returns syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I would have written it like this:

```
select 
    a.item_name, 
    (SELECT base_price FROM f_product_pric(l.id, l.price_list, a.product_class)) as base_price
from lab l, items a
where lab.guid=? .....
```

Comment: Yes, but it needed one suquery per each item from the called function. I solved it definitely by upgrading all instances to 9.3